# Apache - Apply rewrite rule ONLY IF rule file target DOES EXISTS

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

this question may appear the same of always: "Apply rule if file doesn't exists" but: Atention! It's not. It's the inverse.

I want to apply a rewrite rule **only if the result file of the rule actually exists**, and if not, ignore the rule and continue with the next. Example:

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*) apifolder/$1.php
```

If I type the URL: **"api/file1"** and the file **"apifolder/file1.php"** doesn't exists, then I want this rule to be ignored and continue.

I hope the question has been clear. Thanks for your time.

**Edit:**

More info about what I'm trying to accomplish. Given the next 2 rules:

```
RewriteRule  ^api/([^/]+)/(.*)  app/$1/$2.api.php 
RewriteRule  ^api/([^/]+)(.*)  app/$1/$1.api.php
```

If the first rule destiny file doesn't exists, I want the rule be ignored and the second rule execute.

Comment: Have you tried to simply modify the "Apply rule if file doesn't exists" rule?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you. Can you develop the explanation a little more? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can just modify one of many solutions for "Apply rule if file doesn't exists" that can easily be found online?

Comment: I tried with no success. My problem is that "Apply rule if file doesn't exists" applies to an specific writed URL (ex. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f) and not to a **rule target after the rule is evaluated**. Trust me, I made an comprehensive search before post my issue here. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me worked [N] flag. I mean I used first Rule with `[N]`, it forced all rules to apply again but this time `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` worked as a condition to the second rule. Also I needed to use first rule target as a second rule source. It should be something like that:

```
RewriteRule  ^api/([^/]+)/(.*)  app/$1/$2.api.php [N]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule  ^app/([^/]+)/(.*).api.php  app/$1/$1.api.php
```